# Jackson annotations for hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, hibernate-annotations

What is the exact use of @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference, @JsonIgnore, @JsonIdentityInfo. little i know is that they solve recursion problem. Does all the above meant for same purpose.

Comment: Please elaborate: What has your question to do with Hibernate?

Comment: To convert object to json for ajax requests. i am using hibernate ORM